# Why do I get an Error 404 when trying to access to a cakePHP 2.x project in Plesk?

Tags: cakephp, web, web-hosting, plesk, cakephp-2.x

I made a project using cakePHP 2.6.13 and hosted it in Plesk, however whenever I try to access any .php or .ctp page it says that the file does not exist but it can access the .html files without a problem.

I've changed the .htaccess routing but the server still says that the files do not exist.

I'm new at web hosting so I don't know what else to do.

The only error I get says: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".

My .htaccess are:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule    ^$ /app/webroot/    [L]
 RewriteRule    (.*) /app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule    ^$    /webroot/    [L]
 RewriteRule    (.*) /webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolved the server hosting project issue, I preferred first to check the error log, It says where is the problem there.

If I talk about the cakephp there are error log located in tmp directory

For Cakephp2.6.13, make sure following steps
 1. Make sure required extension is enabled in your server
 2. Make sure .htaccess configured properly
 3. Make sure remove the cache directory If you copy paste from your local system to server

Hope this will helpful to you.